# Unable to create db on neo4j using cypher query

Tags: database, neo4j, graph-databases

I am fairly new to neo 4j and trying to create a database by running a cypher query but getting an error that I cant figure out. My query is below. I got the following error

Aggregation column contains implicit grouping expressions. For example, in 'RETURN n.a, n.a + n.b + count(*)' the aggregation expression 'n.a + n.b + count(*)' includes the implicit grouping key 'n.b'

```
 WITH 50.0*1000 as width, 50.0*1000 as height, 10 as x_num, 10 as y_num, 10 as depot_num
 UNWIND RANGE(0, x_num-1) AS x
 UNWIND RANGE(0, y_num-1) AS y
 WITH *, x * width / 110574.0 AS lat
 WITH *, y * height / (111320.0 * COS(lat/360.0)) AS lon CREATE (n:RoadPoint {lat: 
 lat, lon: lon, x: x, y: y})
 WITH DISTINCT x_num, y_num, depot_num
 UNWIND RANGE(0, x_num-1) AS x
 UNWIND RANGE(0, y_num-2) AS y
 MATCH (n:RoadPoint)
 WHERE n.x = x AND n.y = y
 MATCH (m:RoadPoint)
 WHERE m.x = x AND m.y = y+1
 WITH *, DISTANCE( POINT({latitude: n.lat, longitude: n.lon}), POINT({latitude: m.lat, longitude: m.lon})) AS d CREATE (n)-[:ROAD_SEGMENT {distance_meter: d, distance: d/1000.0}]->(m)<-[:ROAD_SEGMENT {distance_meter: d, distance: d/1000.0}]-(n)
 WITH DISTINCT x_num, y_num, depot_num
 UNWIND RANGE(0, x_num-2) AS x
 UNWIND RANGE(0, y_num-1) AS y
 MATCH (n:RoadPoint)
 WHERE n.x = x AND n.y = y
 MATCH (m:RoadPoint)
 WHERE m.x = x+1 AND m.y = y
 WITH *, DISTANCE( POINT({latitude: n.lat, longitude: n.lon}), POINT({latitude: m.lat, longitude: m.lon})) AS d CREATE (n)-[:ROAD_SEGMENT {distance_meter: d, distance: d/1000.0}]->(m)-[:ROAD_SEGMENT {distance_meter: d, distance: d/1000.0}]->(n)
 WITH DISTINCT depot_num
 MATCH (n:RoadPoint)
 WITH depot_num, n, r AND () AS r ORDER BY r DESC
 WITH COLLECT(n)[0..depot_num] AS depot_roads
 UNWIND depot_roads AS depot_road CREATE (:Depot)-[:LOCATED_AT]->(depot_road)
```

Answer (score 0):

your statement doesn't create a database. Furthermore, multiple databases are not part of the community edition of Neo4j.